# Dots in front of <component v-for/>

Tags: vue.js

I've made a website using vuejs and everything worked fine while I used Firefox as a browser. Then I switched to Chrome and all components witht a `v-for` have a dot in the front like in a `<ul>`

What can I do to make them invisible or better do delete them

Comment: try to add this CSS rule `ul{list-style:none}`

Comment: What exactly do you repeat with `v-for`? It's probably not something like `<li v-for='element in myData'>{{ element }}</li>`?

Comment: I am repeating a own component

Comment: Please give some more information such as your component's template, the part of your code containing `v-for` and maybe a screenshot from Chrome.